# How to merge upstream changes into my mirrored internal server

Tags: android, repository

I'm new to git/repo, so forgive me if this is a simple question. I followed the steps below to mirror Android source on my server:

1. repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest --mirror
2. Cloned platform/manifest.git and modifed default.xml to fetch from my server
3. On a desktop ran the comands below to sync the ICS branch with my server, created work branch and pushed to reposity on my server:

   repo init -u git://192.168.1.125/ics-mirror/platform/manifest.git -b android-4.0.1_r1 
   repo sync

   repo start work_branch --all

   repo forall -c 'git remote add corpserver /opt/git/ics-mirror/$REPO_PROJECT.git $@'

   repo forall -c git push corpserver work_branch:refs/heads/work_branch
   repo sync
4. Changed default revision to work_branch

   default revision="refs/heads/work_branch"

So we can now sync our work_branch on desktops by running this command:

repo init -u git://192.168.1.125/ics-mirror/platform/manifest.git -b work_branch

However I just don't know how to merge upstream changes made on the branch android-4.0.1_r1 into our work_branch. A git branch -a lists the following branches:

remotes/aosp/donut-release

remotes/aosp/donut-release2

remotes/aosp/eclair-passion-release

remotes/aosp/eclair-release

remotes/aosp/eclair-sholes-release

remotes/aosp/eclair-sholes-release2

remotes/aosp/froyo

remotes/aosp/froyo-release

remotes/aosp/gingerbread

remotes/aosp/gingerbread-mr4-release

remotes/aosp/gingerbread-release

remotes/aosp/ics-factoryrom-2-release

remotes/aosp/ics-mr0

remotes/aosp/master

remotes/aosp/work_branch

remotes/m/work_branch -> aosp/work_branch

Could anyone please kindly help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked what are the revisions present in manifest files on android-4.0.1_r1 branch?? check manifest files on android-4.0.1_r1 branch in ics-mirror/platform/manifest.git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was posted on the [mailing list where you also asked this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/repo-discuss/LbyNTo_9N64/sv_HIyEbwiEJ)

For posterity:

> I doubt that branch will ever change, but you may want to merge from
>   ics-mr0 or ics-factoryrom-2-release. Just use "git merge" for this:
>
> repo forall -c 'git merge aosp/ics-mr0'
>
> Resolve conflicts (if any) and push back to the server.

Comment: Thanks Marks! I've just forgotten to report back.